# To change the assignment of a trigger in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, triggers, ddl, alter

When I want to insert a column into a existing table (or reduce the size of a field) in Oracle database, I rename it, recreate another table (with the old name) and copy data from the old to the new table.

But in the same time, all triggers attached to the table change according to its new name and I have to:

1. copy the definition of one trigger
2. delete this trigger
3. change the name of the attached table in the trigger's definition
4. recreate the trigger
5. do the same thing for all attached triggers

Is there any way to change the name of the table to which the triggers refer without having to recreate them from scratch?

@Littlefoot
An example :

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));
Table créée.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4    begin
  5      :new.id := seq_test.nextval;
  6    end;
  7  /
Déclencheur créé.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Littlefoot');
1 ligne créée.

SQL> alter table test rename to tmp_test;
Table modifiée.

SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(10));
Table créée.

SQL> insert into test
  2  (select id, substr(name, 10) from tmp_test);
1 ligne créée.

SQL> create or replace TRIGGER trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on "TEST"
  3    for each row
  4    begin
  5      :new.id := seq_test.nextval;
  6    end;
  7  /
create or replace TRIGGER trg_bi_test
                          *
ERREUR à la ligne 1 :
ORA-04095: déclencheur 'TRG_BI_TEST' existe déjà sur une autre table,
imposs. de le remplacer
```

`

And the trigger's body is :

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_bi_test
  before insert on "TMP_TEST"
  for each row
  begin
    :new.id := seq_test.nextval;
  end;
```

As you see, the trigger is attached to the **TMP_TEST** table and I can't 'create or replace' it because of this.

Your sample is correct if you accept to change the name of the working table...

Comment: You have the trigger definition in source code control, right? So why not just reapply it to the table?

Comment: @eaolson Because I have to delete it/them first, then go to source repository and execute the script(s). Each table has 5-6 triggers and it's long and source of errors...

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it on a column level?

For example:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := seq_test.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
        21 Littlefoot

SQL>
```

Adding a new column is easy:

```
SQL> alter table test add (address varchar2(20));

Table altered.
```

Decreasing column name is *tricky*. This one works; trigger is still OK:

```
SQL> alter table test modify name varchar2(15);

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_triggers where trigger_name = 'TRG_BI_TEST';

STATUS
--------
ENABLED
```

This isn't that easy, but - a workaround exists:

```
SQL> alter table test modify id number(4);
alter table test modify id number(4)
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01440: column to be modified must be empty to decrease precision or scale


SQL> -- OK; it failed, so - let's add a new column, put old values in there, 
SQL> -- drop the old column, rename the new column:
SQL> alter table test add id_new number(4);

Table altered.

SQL> update test set id_new = id;

1 row updated.

SQL> alter table test drop column id;

Table altered.

SQL> alter table test rename column id_new to id;

Table altered.

SQL> select status from user_triggers where trigger_name = 'TRG_BI_TEST';

STATUS
--------
ENABLED

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Bigfoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

NAME            ADDRESS                      ID
--------------- -------------------- ----------
Littlefoot                                   21
Bigfoot                                      22

SQL>
```

OK, let's rename the table:

```
SQL> rename test to test_new;

Table renamed.

SQL> insert into test_new (name) values ('Testing');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test_new;

NAME            ADDRESS                      ID
--------------- -------------------- ----------
Littlefoot                                   21
Testing                                      23
Bigfoot                                      22

SQL>
```

As you can see, I didn't have to touch the trigger at all, whatever I did.

If you still have problems, could you edit your message and demonstrate what you did and how Oracle responded?

Comment: Hi, thx, but my question was not about changing columns in a table.
In your sample, you rename the old table to test_new. What happens if you want to preserve the name 'test'?

Comment: It was *preserved* until I renamed it. As I've sadi: post your own test case.

Comment: That's unreadable, Zevet. Please, post that code within the question, the initial message you wrote.